# complex numbers help

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given the following complex numbers:
> $$
> z=1+i\sqrt{3}
> \qquad
> w = 0.707 - 0.707i
> $$
> find the cartesian forms of the following expressions:
> $$
> z^2 \bar{w}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{z^3}{w^9}
> $$

The first one i found the answer to be 1.414 - 1.414i, is this correct?

Comment: As a general tip, multiplication and division of complex numbers is _much_ easier to do in polar form. So I would actually recommend that you convert both $z$ and $w$ to polar, then calculate, then convert back. Especially dividing by the ninth power of $w$ is going to be a mess to do in Cartesian.

Comment: I agree with Arthur. You will see that the polar forms of both $z$ and $w$ are surprisingly simple ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the polar forms of $z$ and $w$, then the calculation becomes much easier as mentioned in the comments.

Suppose that $z=r_{1}e^{i\theta_{1}}$ and $w=r_{2}e^{i\theta_{2}}$, then

$z^{2}\bar{w}=(r_{1}e^{i\theta_{1}})^{2}(r_{2}e^{-i\theta_{2}})=r_{1}^{2}r_{2}e^{i(2\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})}$ and $\frac{z^{3}}{w^9}=\frac{r_{1}^{3}}{r_{2}^{9}}e^{3i(\theta_{1}-3\theta_{2})}.$

Then you can use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): $re^{i\theta}=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ to express your result in the form $x+iy.$

Now since $r_{1}=|z|=2$ and $\theta_{1}=\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1})=\frac{\pi}{3}$
you have that $z=2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}.$ Similarly $w=r_{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}$ where $r_{2}=|w|=\sqrt{(0.707)^2+(0.707)^2}\space(\approx 0.9998489885978).$

Comment: this helped me quite a bit! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Observe that $\;0.707\cong\cfrac1{\sqrt2}\approx\cfrac{\sqrt2}2\;$ , thus

$$w\approx\frac{\sqrt2}2(1-i)$$

Thus the first one is

$$z^2\overline w=(-2+2\sqrt3\,i)\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)=\sqrt2(-1+\sqrt3~i)(1+i)=\sqrt2(-1-\sqrt3-(1-\sqrt3)i)=$$

$$=-\sqrt2\left[(1+\sqrt3+(1-\sqrt3)~\right]$$

Continue from here...

As commented, in polar form is way easier. Choosing the standard argument in [0,2\pi);$ , we get:

$$\;z=2e^{\pi i/4}\;,\;\;w=e^{3\pi i/4}\implies\text{etc.}$$

and etc.

Comment: Do you mean $w\approx\frac{\sqrt2}2(1-i)$?